# Kaa sandbox cqlsh user and password

Tags: kaa

What is the login name and password for Cassandra cqlsh? 
I do not see data in tables ep_profile, ep_user etc. under anonymous access. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Sandbox there are not additional users created for Cassandra database. There  is default user "cassandra".
You can see data using anonymous access. 
By default as NoSQL DB in Sandbox used MongoDB. Check your [NoSQL database configuration](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/#nosql-database).

Configure if it wasn't set to use Cassandra, restart kaa-node service and connect some client to the Kaa.

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr. I understand it now. I found the data in MongoDB.